# Align svg to center of screen

Tags: html, svg

here is my svg

```
<svg id="svgMain" align="center" width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

But its not aligned to the center.How to align it to the center of the screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44963267/3221274

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try CSS:

```
#svgMain {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block;}
```

Comment: try adding `display:block;` to that

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby thnks dat did d trick....

Comment: this only aligns it horizontally...

Answer (score 1):

Include it in a  element.

```
<div text-align="center">
<svg id="svgMain" align="center" width="500" height="500"></svg>
</div>
```

This should work.