# Having charts in center align - d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have three charts that I want all to be in the center of the HTML page. I know that this question has been asked before but none of the solutions worked for me:

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639383/how-do-i-center-an-svg-in-a-div/44963267#44963267) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373169/align-svg-to-center-of-screen) references.

Can you give me a feedback on this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vS7x2tuTC5gDpkdNfzyC?p=preview) in order to have charts in the center of the page?

```
svg{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your SVG's in a parent `div`

```
<div class="svg-container">
   <!-- ...svgs -->
</div>
```

then in your `CSS`

```
 .svg-container{
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

you may also need to adjust the width of the div as well