# How do I center a responsive SVG image?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to align this SVG, horizontally within it's container (in this case it can be any div, body, or whatever.)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1250 190" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" class="svg-content">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="">
                <ellipse cx="442.5" cy="5.5" fill="#172A3A" rx="5.5" ry="5.5"></ellipse>
                <path stroke="#172A3A" d="M806.88 69.082v-4.68c0-12.692-10.29-22.98-22.982-22.98h-316.59c-9.558 0-18.64.828-24.868-6.422-6.228 7.25-15.31 6.42-24.87 6.42H100.983C88.29 41.42 78 51.71 78 64.403v4.68M442.5 11v55.5"></path>
                <ellipse cx="78.001" cy="113.501" fill="#743B41" rx="47.001" ry="47.501"></ellipse>
                <ellipse cx="443.001" cy="113.501" fill="#743B41" rx="47.001" ry="47.501"></ellipse>
                <ellipse cx="78.154" cy="113.54" fill="#172A3A" rx="36.154" ry="36.54"></ellipse>
                <ellipse cx="443.154" cy="113.54" fill="#172A3A" rx="36.154" ry="36.54"></ellipse>
                <text fill="#FFF" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="2">
                    <tspan x="69.177" y="117">72</tspan>
                </text>
                <text fill="#FFF" opacity=".918" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="2">
                    <tspan x="27.471" y="183">Investments</tspan>
                </text>
                <text fill="#FFF" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="2">
                    <tspan x="433.39" y="117">30</tspan>
                </text>
                <text fill="#FFF" opacity=".918" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="2">
                    <tspan x="350.356" y="183">Succesful Trade Sales</tspan>
                </text>
                <ellipse cx="807.001" cy="113.501" fill="#743B41" rx="47.001" ry="47.501"></ellipse>
                <ellipse cx="807.154" cy="113.54" fill="#172A3A" rx="36.154" ry="36.54"></ellipse>
                <text fill="#FFF" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold">
                    <tspan x="800.749" y="117">13</tspan>
                </text>
                <text fill="#FFF" opacity=".918" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold">
                    <tspan x="793.588" y="182.003">IPOs</tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/dtjz225o/ ? Note, that your graphic is currently not centered in the viewport. this might mess with the perception of "centered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 868 190" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" class="svg-content">
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="">
            <ellipse cx="442.5" cy="5.5" fill="#172A3A" rx="5.5" ry="5.5"></ellipse>
            <path stroke="#172A3A" d="M806.88 69.082v-4.68c0-12.692-10.29-22.98-22.982-22.98h-316.59c-9.558 0-18.64.828-24.868-6.422-6.228 7.25-15.31 6.42-24.87 6.42H100.983C88.29 41.42 78 51.71 78 64.403v4.68M442.5 11v55.5"></path>
            <ellipse cx="78.001" cy="113.501" fill="#743B41" rx="47.001" ry="47.501"></ellipse>
            <ellipse cx="443.001" cy="113.501" fill="#743B41" rx="47.001" ry="47.501"></ellipse>
            <ellipse cx="78.154" cy="113.54" fill="#172A3A" rx="36.154" ry="36.54"></ellipse>
            <ellipse cx="443.154" cy="113.54" fill="#172A3A" rx="36.154" ry="36.54"></ellipse>
            <text fill="#FFF" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="2">
                <tspan x="69.177" y="117">72</tspan>
            </text>
            <text fill="#FFF" opacity=".918" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="2">
                <tspan x="27.471" y="183">Investments</tspan>
            </text>
            <text fill="#FFF" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="2">
                <tspan x="433.39" y="117">30</tspan>
            </text>
            <text fill="#FFF" opacity=".918" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold" letter-spacing="2">
                <tspan x="350.356" y="183">Succesful Trade Sales</tspan>
            </text>
            <ellipse cx="807.001" cy="113.501" fill="#743B41" rx="47.001" ry="47.501"></ellipse>
            <ellipse cx="807.154" cy="113.54" fill="#172A3A" rx="36.154" ry="36.54"></ellipse>
            <text fill="#FFF" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold">
                <tspan x="800.749" y="117">13</tspan>
            </text>
            <text fill="#FFF" opacity=".918" font-family="Novecentowide-Bold, Novecento wide" font-size="11" font-style="expanded" font-weight="bold">
                <tspan x="793.588" y="182.003">IPOs</tspan>
            </text>
        </g>
    </svg>


    <style>
     svg {
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-width: 1320px;
     }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639383/how-do-i-center-an-svg-in-a-div).

> SVG is inline by default. Add `display: block` to it and then `margin: auto` will work as expected.