# Centering button in email notification

Tags: css, button, html-table, shopify, center

I'm trying to center a button in the Shopify Email Notification. Tried a few different ways but none were successful.

So far the modified code below works in preview, but not in the test email.

Any idea? Thanks so much!!

```css
.button__cell { 
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translateX(-50%); 
    text-align=center; background: {{ shop.email_accent_color }}; 
}
```

```html
<td class="button__cell"><a href="{{ gift_card.url }}" class="button__text">View Gift Card</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-align=center;` should be `text-align:center;`

You could try `margins` (which has greater [Compatibility](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/margin/)) over `left` [See Compatibility](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/left/) (and `transform` [See Compatibility](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/transforms/transform/)).

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

Both of these properties (`left` and `transform`) lack universal support across the various Email Programs available today (`transform` is not supported by **ANY email program** except for `AOL` or `Android`).

I would suggest using `TABLES` to properly center your content, you'll have greater compatibility across every E-mail application.

**HTML**

```
<td class="button__cell">
    <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ gift_card.url }}" class="button__text">View Gift Card</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

<sub>(source: [What's the best way to center your HTML ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857765/whats-the-best-way-to-center-your-html-email-content-in-the-browser-window-or))</sub>

**CSS**

```
td.button__cell > table {
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
}

td.button__cell > table > tr {
    border: none;
}

td.button__cell > table > tr > td {
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
}
```

*The CSS3 should remove the borders predefined by browsers and center align the text.*

Comment: thank you for the suggestions! I tried margin before but for some reason it doesn't work, not even in preview. table code doesn't work (in shopify notification) either.